# Date formatting from user input

Tags: c#, .net, date

Hai
i am getting a date input(Not the DateTime.Now) from the user and i want that to transform and show in a Date format.
E.g: in the XAML,  will be specified and i want that to be shown as "PrintedOn - October 24,2008" .The string formatting is string.format("{0} - {1}",userText, userDate).
Where am i going wrong?How can i convert the UserDate to the formatting i need. Please pecify the code.
Thanks

Comment: Which language are you talking about? Please re-tag.

Comment: What is the format in the userDate string?

Comment: <UserText="PrintedOn" UserDate="20102009">

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
String.Format("{0} - {1}", userText, Date.Parse(userDate).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy"))
```

where userDate is currently your date as an unspecified format in a string from the XAML. If you know the format it's arriving in, use ParseExact instead.

Comment: this should probably be `String.Format("{0} - {1}", userText, (Convert.ToDateTime(userDate)).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy"))` to correctly answer the question

Comment: Hai,
I think ur answer will work.But i am getting error.So i checked and i found that even the following code is not running.Any ideas?

DateTime dateValue;
string dateString = "2/16/2008 12:15:12 PM";
dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

when i debug, i cant pass the 3rd line..I am getting this error"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: Hai its working after adding this code
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

if you have a date from the user:

[just use DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx)

If you need to get a date from a string, just use

```
DateTime. Parse(datestring)
```

Comment: But i am getting the input from the user as a string(XAML).So how can i convert it to Date?

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample, I assume this is C# or VB.NET.

```
String.Format("{0} - {1}", userText, userDate.ToString("D"))
```

does something along those lines, and gives you a string in the current locale as a bonus. See the [possible format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for more info.